# Cannot call an ObjC method taking int in Swift because Int32 cannot be converted to Int

Tags: objective-c, swift, types

I'm working on a mixed Objective-C and Swift project.
I have a class named `Point`, defined in Objective-C, which has `int` properties and an initializer:

```
@property (nonatomic) int column;
@property (nonatomic) int row;
- (id) initWithColumn:(int)column row:(int)row;
```

which I use to create an object in a Swift file:

```
Point(column: Column, row: Row)
```

But it gives an error:

> cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list with type '(column: Int, row: Int)'

By checking further, I found out that these `int` properties in Objective-C become `Int32` in Swift, and `Int32` cannot be converted to `Int`.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

I wonder how comes that Objective C int becomes Int32 in Swift and how to deal with this so that I can have Int type in Swift from Objective C? I use this class frequently and prefer to keep the type consistent instead of casting each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably avoid using `int` in Objective-C and use `NSInteger` instead, that gets mapped to Swift's `Int`.

Anyway, if you need to convert an `Int` variable, say `n`, to `Int32`, you can do it with

```
var n32: Int32 = Int32(n)
```

so your code would be

```
Point(column: Int32(Column), row: Int32(Row))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is cast from one type to the other.

Try: `Point(column: int(Column), row: int(Row))`

BTW, it is non-standard/confusing to name variable with a name beginning with a upper-case letter in Swift/Objective-C.